# UndoFX: A bound value cannot be set

Tags: javafx, reactfx

I use UndoFX for the undo and redo functions to a rectangle shape.
So far it is working fine for position, size and rotation, **except** the `fillProperty` color of the shape.

The problem is that i can't bind my shape with the `ColorPicker` component, i get infinite exceptions:

> Rectangle.fill: A bound value cannot be set.

How can i use both undofx functions and binding?

```
colorField.valueProperty().setValue((Color) (currentSelected.getRect().fillProperty().getValue()));

currentSelected.getRect().fillProperty().bind(colorField.valueProperty());

previousSelected.getRect().fillProperty().unbind();
```

Comment: The [example from the library documentation](https://github.com/TomasMikula/UndoFX/blob/master/undofx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/undo/demo/CircleProperties.java#L180-L202) does exactly this; have the `redo` for the change in the color change the value of the color picker instead of the value of the circle's fill directly. The binding will ensure the circle's fill is updated.

Comment: @James_D I'm afraid this doesn't apply when there are more than one rectangle. @Senpai, make `currentSelected` an `ObservableValue` and then `bindBidirectional` between `colorField.valueProperty()` and `Val.selectVar(currentSelected, x -> x.getRect().fillProperty())` should do what you expect.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice there were multiple rectangles there. Apologies.

Comment: @TomasMikula
When trying to bindBidirectional:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Var<Object> to Property<Color>

Comment: Ah, `Var` does extend `Property`, but `Rectangle#fillProperty()` is a `Paint`, while `ColorPicker#valueProperty()` is a `Color`. Try to `bindBidirectional` this instead: `Val.selectVar(currentSelected, x -> x.getRect().fillProperty()).mapBidirectional(paintToColor, Function.identity())`, where `Function<Paint, Color> paintToColor = p -> { if(p instanceof Color) return (Color) p; else return null; }`